# How to parallize a code calling a routine from another code (C language)

Tags: c

In my C code I'm calculating some thermodynamic stuff within a loop by calling a routine in written in fortran multiple times. I would like to parallelize the call of this routine.

Because my code is not written in parallel I can't use MPI, so I would like to use something like openMP. However openMP won't work (to my knowledge) because I need to run multiple occurrence of the fortran routine at the same time.

What should I use to be able to run in parallel multiple occurrence of a routine which is called from a C code ?

Thank you

Comment: Threading is what you want. See pthread (linux) or CreateThread (Windows). But OpenMP is able to call several times the same function.

Comment: Maybe `#pragma omp sections` and `#pragma omp section`?

Comment: Is your fortran code and the C code that "wraps" it re-entrant and thread-safe?

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

I'll have a look on pthread. I will also try '#pragma omp sections' using openMP.

However, I don't know if the fortran and the C-wrapper are re-entrant and thread-safe. Is there a way to test it ?

Cheers